# The issues of installing Ubuntu on Windows 7 through virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Windows 7 using VirtualBox. I have created an Ubuntu instance, and am trying to launch the VM that can lead me to input the downloaded Ununtu image. However, this process looks like just taking forever. I am including the related screenshot for the reference. May I know what can be the reason?

[image]

[image]

I also checked the processes being running, there only have three.

[image]

Comment: "May I know what can be the reason?" your system is slow, you have several process hogging resources, etc. It can be anything and everything

Comment: I checked the running processes, which only have three.

Comment: Those are not the only processes @Braiam is referring to.  Please check the Processes Tab in Task Manager.  On an average machine there should be between 45 and 50.

Comment: Just an alternative suggestion would be to install `wubi` and start using `ubuntu`.

Comment: Did you tell virtualbox to use an ISO image for the virtual CD drive, or did you tell it to use the host system's actual CD drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: **I just saw your base memory is 2048 MB. Try lowering this to 512MB or 768MB. 2GB is a bit excessive unless you have a good reason to do so.**

Try restarting your PC first. Your screenshot shows only the applications. Try switching to the processes tab and check. Close all unnecessary applications including the ones in the system tray.

1. Your virtualbox installation might be faulty. Uninstall, download latest version, then reinstall. Make sure everything is fresh. Happens occasionally.
2. Is **your Ubuntu ISO good? It might have been corrupted.**
3. Make sure you are selecting the right ISO.
4. Make sure your PC can handle it, especially RAM and Graphics. Try allocating a little less RAM and a few more processors to the VM.